# Using SSL with Netty at the beginning of a connection, then disabling it

Tags: multithreading, ssl, netty

I'm writing a server application and its client counterpart that both use Netty for the network layer. I find myself facing typical safety concerns about sending a password from a client to the server so I decided SSL was the safest way of doing this.

I know of the [securechat](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html) example and will use this to modify my pipelines accordingly. However, I would also like to disable SSL after password transmission and acknowledge to save a few precious CPU cycles on server side, which may be busy with many other clients. The [ChannelPipeline](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) documentation states that:

> "Once attached, the coupling between the channel and the pipeline is permanent; the channel cannot attach another pipeline to it nor detach the current pipeline from it."

The idea is then to not change the pipeline on-the-fly, which is prohibited, but to somehow tell the *SslHandler* in the pipeline that it should stop encrypting messages at some point. I was thinking of creating a class inheriting from *SslHandler*, overriding its *handleDownstream* function to call *context.sendDownstream(evt)* after some point in the communication.

*Question 1*: Is this a bad idea, that is, disabling SSL at some point ?

To allow a block in the pipeline (say a *Decoder*) telling another block (say *SslHandler*) that it should change its behaviour from now on, I thought I could create, say, an *AtomicBoolean* in my *ChannelPipelineFactory*'s *getPipeline()* and pass it to the constructor of both the *Decoder* and the *SslHandler*.

*Question 2*: Is this a bad idea, that is, sharing state between pipeline blocks ? I'm worried I might screw up the multithreading of Netty here: are the blocks of a pipeline working on a single message, one at a time ? i.e.: does the first block wait for the completion of the last block before pulling the next message ?

**EDIT:**

Oh my bad, this is from the [ChannelPipeline](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) page I had been visiting many times and quoting in this very question:

> "A ChannelHandler can be added or removed at any time because a ChannelPipeline is thread safe. For example, you can insert a SslHandler when sensitive information is about to be exchanged, and remove it after the exchange."

So this answers question 2 about modifying the pipeline's *content* on-the-fly, and not the pipeline reference itself.

Comment: I realize now asking two questions in one post was a bad idea, since now I cannot accept two answers each addressing one question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the efficacy of turning off SSL once established, but I think you have misinterpreted the mutability of the pipeline. Once a given channel is associated with a pipeline, that association is immutable. However, the handlers in the pipeline can be safely modified. That is to say,  you can add and remove handlers as your protocol requires.  Accordingly,you should be able to remove the SSL handler once it has served its purpose.

Comment: I had more than misinterpreted that mutability: it seems I overlooked the very part of the documentation directly answering my 2nd question. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `SslHandler` from the pipeline with `ChannelPipeline.remove(..)` then it should turn your connection to plaintext.  Please file a bug if it does not work - we actually have not tried that scenario in production :-)

Comment: removing sslhandler triggers [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/d34212439068091bcec29a8fad4df82f0a82c638/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#L702) line - but `!handshakePromise.isDone()` is not checked there - is it expected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Netty, but in principle, you could indeed carry on with plain traffic on the same TCP connection. There are a few downsides:

- Only the authentication would be secured. A MITM could perform actions other than those intended by the user. (This is similar to using HTTP Digest to some extent: the credentials are protected, but the request/response entities aren't.)
- From an implementation point of view, this is tricky to get right. The [TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246#section-7.2.1) says:

  > If the application protocol using TLS provides that any data may be
  > carried over the underlying transport after the TLS connection is
  > closed, the TLS implementation must receive the responding
  > `close_notify` alert before indicating to the application layer that
  > the TLS connection has ended.

  This implies that you're going to synchronise your stream somehow to wait for the `close_notify` response, before carrying on with your plain traffic.
  The `SSLEngine` programming model is rather complex, and you may find that the Netty API isn't necessary handling this situation.

While it may make sense to want to save a few CPU cycles, most of the SSL/TLS overhead is in the handshake, which you'll be doing anyway. The symmetric cryptographic operations used for the actual encryption of the data are much less expensive. (You should try to measure this overhead to see if it really is a problem.)